# Monitor all outgoing http request from my app WHITIN my app (java)

Tags: java, http, proxy

Is there a way in java to monitor my outgoing http requests (with code inside the sending app)?

Lets say that in my app, sometimes method **a** sends http requests from a jetty server, and somtimes method **b** sends http request from a netty server (or any other way..) ,maybe even in paralel.

I want to have a thread in my app that run in paralel to my app and will catch all outgoing requests and manipulates them and then resend..  (proxy).

EDITED: No class in the app should know that this proxy exist.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: You could create a proxy HTTP client that you would use everywhere in your application. The proxy would do whatever you wish with the request then use some delegate HTTP client to actually send the request. This requires cooperation from all senders though.

Comment: @JiriTousek tnx for the reply. I want it to be done without the cooperation of the senders.